# Declaring a singleton in java the right way, and init the private hashtable correctly

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, hashtable

I need some guidance on how to initialize this hash inside a singleton.

So according to the author of effective java, you declare a singleton using an enumeration: https://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded/effective_java_reloaded.pdf?attredirects=0

So I have this so far:

```
public enum MySingleton {
  INSTANCE;

  private final Hashtable<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings;

  public final UserSettings getSettings(SomeEnumType enumType) {
     return settings.get(enumType);
  }

}
```

So I think I have my singleton correct, I need help on how I can initialize the settings hashtable inline.

```
private final Hashtable<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings = new Hashtable<SomeEnumType, UserSettings>() {{
  put(SomeEnumType.Blah1, new UserSettings ???????  );
}};
```

Say my UserSettings has some fields, can I set them inline?
Any comments on the singleton, is it ok?

Note:  I will not be updating this hash at all after I initialize it.

Comment: Commenting on your code... *Hashtable* are a bit Java 1.2.  Typically you can use a *HashMap* instead.  Besides that I don't think that here anyway you should use a map between *SomeEnumType* and *UserSettings*.  If you have an enum, you have ordinals and you can directly access an array, for example using something like that: *UserSettings[enumType.ordinal]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're not updating the `Hashtable`, you don't require synchronization, so I'd use a `HashMap` instead.  You have 2 options to initialize the map.

1) In the enum constructor

```
public enum MySingleton {
  INSTANCE;

  private final HashMap<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings;

  private MySingleton(){
    settings = new HashMap<SomeEnumType, UserSettings>();
    settings.put(...,...);
  }

  public final UserSettings getSettings(SomeEnumType enumType) {
     return settings.get(enumType);
  }

}
```

2) In an initializer block

```
public enum MySingleton {
  INSTANCE;

  private final HashMap<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings;
  {
    settings = new HashMap<SomeEnumType, UserSettings>();
    settings.put(...,...);
  }

  public final UserSettings getSettings(SomeEnumType enumType) {
     return settings.get(enumType);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google says [Singleton is harmful](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/) - not OK.

The right way to write it, if you must, is laid out by Joshua Bloch in "Effective Java".

http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/singleton-in-java-the-proper-way/

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that what I have done?  I have the enum with instance; ??

Comment: All I want to have is a static representation of userSettings that I initialize in my code.  How should I be doing this then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the use of enuns for Singletons.  The approach I prefer is to make use of static initializers as follows:

```
public class MySingleton {

      private final Hashtable<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings;

      // As this is static, the VM makes sure that this is called only once
      private static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton(); 

      // We know the contstructor is called only once.  Making it private
      // guarentees no other classes can call it.
      // ==> Thus this is a nice safe place to initialize your Hash
      private MySingleton {
          settings = new Hashtable<SomeEnumType, UserSettings>();
      }

      public static MySingleton getInstance() {
          return INSTANCE;
      }

     public final UserSettings getSettings(SomeEnumType enumType) {
         return settings.get(enumType); 
     }
}
```

And callers access your map as follows:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().getSettings(someEnum);
```

Presumably, your singleton does something other than just manage the Hash.  Otherwise a much simpler approach would be to simply make the Hash itself static.

Another common approach to singletons (which I dont like as well) is to do on-demand creation of the singleton instance as follows:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton instance;

    private MySingleton() {}

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)  instance = new MySingleton ();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The reason I don't like this as much is that it requires syncronization of the getInstance() method to guarantee thread safety.  You take a small performance hit for this.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are generally bad, they are a kind of global variables.

To answer the question, if you need to initialize your table inside that singleton, you can simply use an initialization block (as you did for the elements), but in the singleton.

```
public enum MySingleton {
  INSTANCE;

  private final Map<SomeEnumType, UserSettings> settings;
  {
    settings = new EnumMap(SomeEnumType.class);
    settings.put(...); // etc.
  }
  public final UserSettings getSettings(SomeEnumType enumType) {
   return settings.get(enumType);
  }
}
```